# .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException:

Tags: android, .net, mobile, https, maui

I have a application I am building for R&D that makes HTTPS queries to an ERP API Layer. On windows machines it works perfectly, however, whenever I run an android emulator or connect to a physical device I get SSL errors. I know for a fact the the server accepts TLSv1.2 or 1.3 which I have read is used by default for .net MAUI. I have spent all day on this and can't figure out how to make the request. I have seen a lot of other posts regarding this however they are mostly trying to connect to a local API and try to bypass SSL. I am trying to connect to a test server for our ERP and do not wish to bypass SSL.

**Manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="34" android:minSdkVersion="33" />
</manifest>
```

**Service**:

```
public class JDEService : IJDEService
    {
        private HttpClientHandler httpHandler;
    
        public JDEService()
        {
            httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        }
    
        public async Task<List<WORoutings>> GetWORouting(int WorkOrderNumber)
        {
            
            var baseURL = "*********************************";            
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
            List<WORoutings> routings = new List<WORoutings>();            
            var auth = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(<AUTH STUFF HERE>));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(<AUTH STUFF HERE>);
            try
            {
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{baseURL}<URLHERE>");
                var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
    
                    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WORoutingRoot>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                    routings = json.SF_DREQ_F3112_GetWORouting.rowset;
                    return routings;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception($"ERROR: {response.StatusCode} \n Message: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
    
            return routings;
        }
    }
```

**Logs**:

```
TNET]   --- End of managed Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException stack trace ---
[DOTNET] javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Read error: ssl=0x7ad5ffc45418: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
[DOTNET] error:10000460:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_NO_APPLICATION_PROTOCOL (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:594 0x7ad61fc78358:0x00000001)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:363)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.convertException(ConscryptEngine.java:1134)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:919)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:858)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.-$$Nest$mprocessDataFromSocket(Unknown Source:0)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:241)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:220)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
[DOTNET] Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x7ad5ffc45418: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
[DOTNET] error:10000460:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_NO_APPLICATION_PROTOCOL (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:594 0x7ad61fc78358:0x00000001)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:569)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
[DOTNET]    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876)
[DOTNET]    ... 18 more
[DOTNET] 
[DOTNET]    at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.<>c__DisplayClass133_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 536
[DOTNET]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
[DOTNET]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__281_0(Object obj)
[DOTNET]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[DOTNET] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[DOTNET]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[DOTNET]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
[DOTNET] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[DOTNET]    at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.DoProcessRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, URL javaUrl, HttpURLConnection httpConnection, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestRedirectionState redirectState) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 591
[DOTNET]    at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.DoSendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 456
[DOTNET]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
[DOTNET]    at MauiApp1.Services.JDEService.GetWORouting(Int32 WorkOrderNumber) in C:\Users\dtujo\source\repos\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\Services\JDEService.cs:line 28
```

Comment: There is an issue about this problem: [Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19092).